# Passing threads a value from a for loop

Tags: c, multithreading, loops

I am attempting to create threads and pass each thread the value from a for loop. Here is the code segment

```
pthread_t *threadIDs;
    int i = 0;
    if(impl == 1)
    {
        threadIDs = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*reduces);
        for(;i < reduces; i++)
        {
            pthread_create(&threadIDs[i], NULL, reduce,&i);
        }
    }
```

It is not passing the correct values of the loop, which makes sense since I am creating a race condition. What is the simplest way to pass the correct value of i from my loop?

Another question, will each thread finish executing before the next one is created and called?

Comment: allocate an int as you do with phtread_t could be a solution.

Comment: @u__: There definitely is! The same address is passed to each thread, although the value it points to is changed before a new thread is created.

Comment: Ohh yes.. thank for correcting me

Answer (score 2):

> What is the simplest way to pass the correct value of i from my loop?

What is to be considered "*simple*" depends on the use case, so here another approach to solve the issues you present:

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t m_init;
pthread_cond_t c_init;

int init_done = 1;

void* thread_function(void * pv)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_init);

  size_t i = *((size_t*) pv);
  init_done = 1;

  pthread_cond_signal(&c_init);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_init);

  ...
}

#define THREADS_MAX (42)

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread[THREADS_MAX];

  pthread_mutex_init(&m_init, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&c_init, NULL);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < THREADS_MAX; ++i)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_init);

    init_done = 0;
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thread_function, &i);

    while (!init_done)
    {
      pthread_cond_wait(&c_init);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_init);
  }

  ...
}
```

<sup>(error checking omitted for the sake of legibility)</sup>

Comment: Calling `pthread_mutex_unlock()` on a mutex not locked by the callng thread is either [undefined behavior or an error](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), depending on the type of mutex.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Thanks. I understand my PThreads got rusty. Fixed it?

Comment: Probably easier in this case to have the child thread call `sem_post()` while the parent calls `sem_wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've already dynamically created an array of thread IDs.  Do the same for the values you want to pass in.

```
pthread_t *threadIDs;
int *values;
int i = 0;
if(impl == 1)
{
    threadIDs = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*reduces);
    values = malloc(sizeof(int)*reduces);
    for(;i < reduces; i++)
    {
        values[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&threadIDs[i], NULL, reduce, &values[i]);
    }
}
```

Each thread will be working with a different array member, so there's no race condition.

Comment: I added this, however, when I print the indexes I get in the reduce(void*) method, I get the values from 0-3 in the wrong order, and I should be getting 0-10 in the correct order. Am I doing something wrong when creating my threads?

Comment: printing in wrong order is more to do with your i/o if its is buffered or not ( if its a printf family of calls don't believe the output ) , scheduling of threads so on so forth..

Comment: Would that explain why I am not getting the full range of numbers I am expecting? I should get 0-10, but I am only getting 0-3 @u__

Comment: perhaps ... if your main thread exits before the buffer being flushed you'll probably not see the output at all. give a couple of seconds of sleep after the for loop in main thread and see.. or a pthread_join

Comment: @u__ Yeah, that was it. I added in a sleep(1) and it printed out everything as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can define a structure and assign i to the variable of the object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct Param_ {
    int index;
}Param;

static void* thread(void* p) {
    Param* param = p;
    printf("index: %d\n", param->index);
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int reduces = 10;
    pthread_t *threadIDs;

    threadIDs = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*reduces);
    for(; i < reduces; i++)
    {
        Param* p;
        p = (Param*)malloc(sizeof(*p));
        p->index = i;
        pthread_create(&threadIDs[i], NULL, thread, p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```